# Implicit convex closed surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, surfaces

Are there many examples of smooth closed convex surfaces defined in a implicit way?

The only example that comes to my mind are the ellipses $f^{-1}(0)$ where

$$
f(x,y,z)=x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1, \quad x,y,z\in\Bbb R.
$$

Closed means that it is compact and without boundary and convex means that for each point of the surface, it is in one of the half spaces determined by its tangent plane.

Comment: I mean, you could consider your favourite compact potato with smooth boundary $\partial P$, and then consider some $C^\infty$ function $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=\partial P$ (which exists because $\partial P$ a closed subset).

Comment: Here's a larger class of examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics

Comment: And here's a closed convex surface with no symmetry (my favourite compact potato) : $$x^4+y^4-x^2z+x^2+y^2+z^2-x-y-1=0$$